# how to create a relation between a variable and a parameters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a relation between the variable and parameters. I create a variable called `pagetoken` and give it a static value like `abc`. I try to use it in a function but get an error that says 'pagetoken is undefined'; why?

```
var pagetoken = 'abc'; 

function(num, pagetoken) {
    jQuery.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + escape(phrase) + '&maxResults=8&type=video&key=mykey&pageToken=' + pagetoken, function(data) {
        // an so on..
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you pass anything to your function?

Comment: yes ,actually pagetoken is dynamically changed there value but at first it is blank so i take the variable and set a static value but it give a error that that pagetoken is undifined.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things with syntax that I'm noticing.  By using what you have, I can get this to work in JSFiddle with

```
var pagetoken = 'abc';

function getToken (num, pagetoken) {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=0&maxResults=8&type=video&key=mykey&pageToken=' + pagetoken,
        function (data) {
            // an so on..
        }
    );
}
getToken(0, pagetoken);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/5cd9otee/

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from your scope issue. If you define "pagetoken" outside the function, then you don't need to pass it in as a parameter.

`var pagetoken = 'abc';
 function func_name(num) { // pagetoken is grabbed from above }`

If you want to pass something in, then make sure you call it with the variable as an argument.

`var pagetoken = 'abc';
 func_name (num, pagetoken);`